# python left and right arrow key event not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and trying to create a turtle shape and once the user clicks the left or right arrow keys on keyboard the shape should move in that direction, however nothing is happening.

I am trying to move the player using the left and right arrow keys, buts its not working please help and advice.

```
 #Create the player turtle
    player = turtle.Turtle()
    player.color("blue")
    player.shape("triangle")
    player.penup()
    player.speed(0)
    player.setposition(0, -235)
    player.setheading(90)

    playerspeed = 15


    #Move the player Left and Right
    def move_left():
        x = player.xcor()
        x -= playerspeed
        if x < -200:
            x = - 200
        player.setx(x)

    def move_right():
        x = player.xcor()
        x +- playerspeed
        if x < -200:
            x = - 280
        player.setx(x)

#Create Keyboard Bindings
    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onkey(move_left,"Left")
    turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")
```

Comment: For one thing, in `move_right()`, you say `x +- playerspeed` instead of `x += playerspeed`.  I'm assuming that's a typo, but who knows.

Comment: I have corrected this, however, player still not moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `turtle.mainloop()` at the end of the script, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.mainloop

This works (it shows a blue triangle turtle that moves left or right depending in the cursor keys pressed; it includes the fix suggested by [@zondo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5827958/zondo)):

```
import turtle

#Create the player turtle
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("blue")
player.shape("triangle")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0, -235)
player.setheading(90)

playerspeed = 15


#Move the player Left and Right
def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed
    if x < -200:
        x = - 200
    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    if x < -200:
        x = - 280
    player.setx(x)

#Create Keyboard Bindings
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")

#Start the main loop
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have called the mainloop but not showed it in the above code. could you advice

Comment: You're welcome; please mark the answer as selected, so other people know this question is answered.